# Datastax - Cassandra data stored in two location against cassandra.yaml configuration file

Tags: amazon-ec2, cassandra, datastax

I have launched Amazon Datastax AMI - EC2(m3.medium) instance to run cassandra with following storage configuration.

one root volume(instance store) - 8 GB.
one EBS-IOPS volume - 50 GB.

With the above configuration, I can run cassandra.

My Problem is, When I create sample keyspace with table and its data,the data are stored in below two location

/var/lib/cassandra/data/  AND /mnt/cassandra/data

But in cassandra.yaml, I configured data directory should be on /mnt/cassandra/data.

Could any one please help me to find out "Why data are stored in two different location?". I would like to data must be present on my EBS volume only.

Thanks

Comment: What are the data stored in `/var/lib/cassandra/data/` ? How big is this folder ? I suspect that there are 2 `cassandra.yaml` files that are pointing to different data folder. Also, did you change the `cassandra.yaml` in the past to point to  `/mnt/cassandra/data` or is it already the default conf value ?

Comment: Both file path /var/lib/cassandra/data/ AND /mnt/cassandra/data having same data and its size also same. As per your suggestion, I confirm that there is only one cassandra.yaml. I have used this command to search "sudo find / -type f -name "cassandra.yaml""

Comment: Can you post here the extract of your `cassandra.yaml` file for the property `data_file_directories` ?

Comment: # Directories where Cassandra should store data on disk.  Cassandra
# will spread data evenly across them, subject to the granularity of
# the configured compaction strategy.
# If not set, the default directory is $CASSANDRA_HOME/data/data.
data_file_directories:
     - /mnt/cassandra/data

# commit log.  when running on magnetic HDD, this should be a
# separate spindle than the data directories.
# If not set, the default directory is $CASSANDRA_HOME/data/commitlog.
commitlog_directory: /mnt/cassandra/commitlog